# How to hide textarea but keep caret visible?

Tags: css, caret

I wonder if I can keep a caret visible while reducing a textarea's opacity to zero.
Actually, what I want to do is to render text strings invisible while having a visible caret that's exactly where it would be if the text was visible.

Comment: That should be possible. Have you tried `color: transparent`?

Comment: i ve tried that but  that changes the caret's color as well so everything becomes transparent... thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pseudo-element like this:

```
p.article::first-letter {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

for an HTML like this:

```
<p class="article">A paragraph in an article</p>
```

Check this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/CSS_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: how does this apply to the OP's question?

Comment: I can't find a way to apply this directly to the caret. it would be great if you could give me some code.

Comment: check this example I made: http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/CaCBe/ this is just an example, you could play with the possibilities, but mind you that it may not work in IE7 or bellow, and you may need a javascript solution.

Comment: @antonis if it worked mark my answer as approved (the √ mark)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using the `color` property on the textarea. Setting it to `transparent` will make the text transparent.
Also, if you don't want the text to be selected you should set the `user-select` property to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS3 UI spec. defines a `caret-color` property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#propdef-caret-color), which allows you to style the caret independently from the text.

Unfortunately that property is not implemented in browser yet, as far as I know.
For Gecko (Firefox) there is at least a [bug report for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1063162).